# Getting URL data with JavaScript (split it like php $_GET)

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, split, window.location

I found this script at Stack Overflow:

```
window.params = function(){
    var params = {};
    var param_array = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
    for(var i in param_array){
        x = param_array[i].split('=');
        params[x[0]] = x[1];
    }
    return params;
}();
```

This splits a URL into data, like PHP does with `$_GET`.

I have another function, which uses it and it refreshes the iframe. I want to get the data from the URL and add another with it if some of these data exist. [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) shows me, that `search` is not defined, but why?

```
function RefreshIFrames(MyParameter) {
    var cat = window.params.cat;
    var category = window.params.category;
    var search = window.params.search;

    if (search.length>0 && category.length>0){
        window.location.href="http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php?search="+search+"&category="+category+"&rendez="+MyParameter;
    }

    if (cat.length>0){
        window.location.href="http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php?cat="+cat+"&rendez="+MyParameter;
    }

    if (cat.length==0 && category.length==0 && search.length==0){
        window.location.href="http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php?rendez="+MyParameter;
    }
    alert(window.location);
}
```

Comment: What is the URL you call your page with? Also you will likely not see the alert since the page will change before the alert statement is reached

Comment: If you are working with firebug use "console.log(window.params);" at the beginning of your function to see the array in firebug. If the page change removes the log from firebug, skip the window.location.href call to analyze the array data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add rendez OR change the existing rendez, do this - I am assuming the URL is actually beginning with http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php so no need to create it. Let me know if you need a different URL than the one you come in with

The parameter snippet did not work proper (for in should not be used on a normal array)

Here is tested code

- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4q2EN/)
- [DEMO WITH DROPDOWN](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/77Evd/show/?rendez=xxx&search=bla)

```
function getParams(passedloc){
  var params = {}, loc = passedloc || document.URL;
  loc = loc.split('?')[1];
  if (loc) {
    var param_array = loc.split('&');
    for(var x,i=0,n=param_array.length;i<n; i++) {
      x = param_array[i].split('=');
      params[x[0]] = x[1];
    }
  }
  return params;
};

function RefreshIFrames(MyParameter,passedloc) { // if second parm is specified it will take that 
  var loc = passedloc || document.URL; // 
  window.param = getParams(loc); 
  loc = loc.split("?")[0]+"?"; // will work with our without the ? in the URL
  for (var parm in window.param) {
    if (parm != "rendez") loc += parm +"="+ window.param[parm]+"&";
  }
  // here we have a URL without rendez but with all other parameters if there
  // the URL will have a trailing ? or & depending on existence of parameters
  loc += "rendez="+MyParameter;
  window.console && console.log(loc)
  // the next statement will change the URL
  // change window.location to window.frames[0].location to change an iFrame
  window.location = loc; 
}

// the second parameter is only if you want to change the URL of the page you are in
RefreshIFrames("rendez1","http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php?cat=cat1&search=search1");
RefreshIFrames("rendez2","http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php?search=search2");
RefreshIFrames("rendez3","http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php?rendez=xxx&search=search2");
RefreshIFrames("rendez4","http://siriusradio.hu/kiskunfelegyhaza/video/index.php");

// here is how I expect you want to call it    
RefreshIFrames("rendez5"​); // will add or change rendez=... in the url of the current page
```

Comment: What happens if the url is like that:

http://somewhat.hu/index.php?cat=2&search=Something

Will it add rendez to the end of the url?

Comment: But there's a little problem with it: If there's rendez in the url and I want to change it, it won't change it :(

Comment: Oh, I see it works. But how about my another problem when rendez exists. It won't change it's value if i choose another value for it.

Comment: So if I use this:

<select name="rendezes" class="rendezes" ONCHANGE="RefreshIFrames('rendez'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, Document.url)">

It will works? :)

Comment: Yes, and so will ONCHANGE="RefreshIFrames('rendez'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) since document.URL is default if nothing is passed

Comment: Well, it seems something wrong with it.

I passes nev, datum and hit value with rendez. Can it be the problem?

Comment: Look here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/77Evd/show/?rendez=xxx&search=bla